# Installing python modules through proxy

Tags: python, proxy, urllib2

I want to install a couple of python packages which use easy_install. They use the urrlib2 module in their setup script. I tried using the company proxy to let easy_install download the required packages. So to test the proxy conn I tried the following code. I dont need to supply any credentials for proxy in IE.

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http":"http://mycompanyproxy-as-in-IE:8080"})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
site = urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com")

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in
 return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 406, in
  response = meth(req, response)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 519, in
  'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 444, in
return self._call_chain(*args)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in
   result = func(*args)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 527, in
   raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg
  urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 407: AuthorizedOnly
```

Is it a problem with my code? or is the proxy not allowing a connection from the python process?. I can install R packages by setting the proxy.

Comment: Are you sure that your company proxy doesn't need credentials? Maybe IE remembers some credentials that were entered by you a long time ago, or by your company's IT staff?

Comment: Maybe , I am not sure if its the same as the login credentials for my PC or intranet passowrd? for updating packages in R I just use the --internet2 option.

Comment: If your computer is a member of a domain, and your proxy is a Windows server, your proxy almost certainly wants your domain login. Worse, it may want it in NTLM.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Set the following environment variables:

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@your-company-proxy.com:8080
```

as well as

```
HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:password@your-company-proxy.com:8080
```

If your proxy port is not 8080, you should change 8080 with the appropriate port number too.
If you don't have rights to modify the global system variables (you can only do so if you have local Admin rights), simply add it to your user-level variables.

Set it from `My Computer > Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables` (or "Advanced Properties" if in Windows 7)

Once you have that variable set, close all `cmd` windows and launch your command prompt again. Then you can use the normal setuptools `easy_install` and `pip` to download and install Python packages.

If you need to use it via Python; the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) library takes care of the quirks of `httplib` and `urllib`.

`requests` will automatically read `HTTP_PROXY` and use the proxy; but here is how you would do it manually (example from the [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies)):

```
import requests

proxies = {
  "http": "http://user:pass@foo.bar.zoo:8080",
  "https": "http://user:pass@foo.bar.zoo:8080",
}

requests.get("http://example.org", proxies=proxies)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can execute following command:

**sudo pip --proxy < proxy > install < module >**

Answer (score 1):

via Windows cmd/PowerShell using setx http_proxy and https_proxy worked.

Both were needed as simply setting http_proxy was not sufficient.

As mentioned above but configured for Windows:

setx HTTP_PROXY http://user:password@your-company-proxy.com:8080

as well as

setx HTTPS_PROXY http://user:password@your-company-proxy.com:8080

Answer (score -1):

The error says that you need to authorization also.
Try following code:

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http":"http://mycompanyproxy-as-in-IE:8080"})
proxy_auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
proxy_auth_handler.add_password('realm', 'host', 'username', 'password')
opener = build_opener(proxy, proxy_auth_handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
site = urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com")
```

I think this should work.

Comment: Is 'realm' the domain which I login to?. What is 'host'?

Comment: -- add_password(realm, uri, user, passwd) -- 

'realm' is just information, its a string, for example: "XYZ Application", uri can be either a single URI, or a sequence of URIs. realm, user and passwd must be strings. This causes (user, passwd) to be used as authentication tokens when authentication for realm and a super-URI of any of the given URIs is given.