# easy_install as a non-root user, received Download error: [Errno -2], but cpan download works

Tags: python, easy-install

Here is my setup:

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2
Non-root user

```
$easy_install –version
Distribute 0.6.10

Perl 5.10.1

Python 2.6.6
```

When I run the following, easy_install command as a non-root user it fails.  I do not have root access:

```
[frank@simunec1 perl]$ easy_install --prefix /nas1_home4/frank/local docutils
Searching for docutils
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/docutils/
Download error: [Errno -2] Name or service not known -- Some packages may not be found!
```

Here are some of the things I have tried, and what does work (see 3):

1)  If I manually download the package to my Windows machine and upload to the Linux server and navigate to the directory containing the source, then the easy_install command above succeeds.  But I am looking to have this command initiate the download successfully.

2)  I would get back a access denied HTML output file if I use curl, ie.

```
Curl –O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py.
```

3)  The Linux server is behind a proxy server.  I have set the http_proxy variable.  More importantly, after setting that variable along with FTP_PASSIVE, I am able to download Perl modules through the cpan installer when I wasn't able to do so before.  I have read that Python uses the same http_proxy environment variable, so why is the easy_install download still failing?

4) What do I need to ask for from the network administrator to make this work?

Thanks.

### UPDATE 1:

I have set my http_proxy variables as follows:

In my .cshrc file,
setenv HTTP_PROXY 'http://username:password@proxy.company.co.jp:10080'
setenv http_proxy 'http://username:password@proxy.company.co.jp:10080'

When I run the CPAN installer, I would still get proxy authentication needed message whether I specify the username/password in my http_proxy string or not.  And if I enter the same username and password, then the install will succeed:

```
$perl –MCPAN –e shell
cpan[1]>force install Time::Clock
Proxy authentication needed!
 (Note: to permanently configure username and password run
   o conf proxy_user your_username
   o conf proxy_pass your_password
 )

 Username:
```

In the Python easy_install case, I don’t get prompted the proxy username/password.  It fails simply with

```
$easy_install --prefix /nas1_home4/frank/local docutils
```

Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/docutils/

No local packages or download links found for docutils

error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('docutils'):

Comment: Give the exact line you used to set the proxy variable. also, try using ```HTTP_PROXY``` as well as ```http_proxy```.

Comment: @korylprince I have added my http_proxy variable under UPDATE1.  Thanks.

Comment: see the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144289/installing-python-modules-through-proxy . See if that helps.

Comment: @korylprince Setting HTTP_PROXY as I have in UPDATE1 still yields the same error, and I was not prompted with proxy authentication password as in the Perl CPAN install case.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. Don't know what else to try. You might try emailing the python mailing list.